# Reading data from a dynamically created set of form fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC and trying to use jQuery to read data from a dynamically created set of form fields. The code I am using to generate the fields is as follows (this is just a test sample and not the complete MVC View):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> Dynamically create input fields- jQuery </title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div id="itemRows">
            Item quantity: <input type="text" name="add_qty" size="4" />
            Item name: <input type="text" name="add_name" />
            <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add row" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var rowNum = 0;
        function addRow(frm) {
            rowNum++;
            var row = '<p id="rowNum' + rowNum + '">Item quantity: <input type="text" name="qty[]" size="4" value="' + frm.add_qty.value + '"> Item name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="' + frm.add_name.value + '"> <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow(' + rowNum + ');"></p>';
            jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
            frm.add_qty.value = '';
            frm.add_name.value = '';
        }
        function removeRow(rnum) {
            jQuery('#rowNum' + rnum).remove();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am just not getting the concept on how to read the added fields and the view source is of no help.

Comment: do you want to read the values in controller?

Comment: no, read on the client side, once thats done, I can use JSON to send the data to the  API controller.

Comment: Your manually generating controls with `name` attributes that could not possibly have any relationship to any model that you want to post back. Show your model and the controller method so we can understand what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured out by adding the index value to the end of the ID will work in a for loop and to get the max value of the index simply reference `rowNum`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize your `form` data to **JSON** you can just serialize full `form` and then find your added fields in **JSON** object:

```
 var form = $('form'); //care if you have multiple forms on your page
 var formData = JSON.stringify(form.serializeArray());
```

Now `formData` variable contains all inputs in your form. If you have many inputs - you get an array.

Comment: I was planning on converting the data to JSON after validating it first. So how do I read the values from the multiple fields individually?

Comment: and what is the problem validate values in json object? you can easily do it with for loop.

Comment: The problem is that I need to pull specific field data before conversion to JSON. Basically, I just need a way to read the individual fields without serialization.